# onload=function vs window.onload=function

Tags: javascript, onload

Are there any real advantages to using window.onload=function(){}; over onload=function(){}; ? I know window.onload looks more proper, but that's not a good reason for me to choose it, especially that it's longer/slower than onload.

After some time-consuming searches and tests, those 2 were the only 2 browser compatible methods, the tests (on relatively new Chrome/Firefox versions, and IE from 5.5 to 9) included:

```
window.onload // works in all tested browsers
onload // works in all tested browsers, faster than window.onload
document.onreadystatechange // works twice in some browsers, once in some others, could be confusing
window.onpageshow // works in chrome and firefox, not in IE
window.onreadystatechange // doesn't work
document.onload // doesn't work
document.onpageshow // doesn't work
window.document.onload // doesn't work
```

I could find this article which is one of the most suited articles to my question:

http://perfectionkills.com/onloadfunction-considered-harmful/

It states that the strict mode of [ECMA-262 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (*"use strict";* which I don't plan to use in my project) could finally cause some browser incompatibility to onload (ReferenceError in Firefox and Opera).

So the question is: are there any real disadvantages related to using the direct onload assignment other than the "use strict;" one? I need infos not some unexplained opinions.

Thanks

**Note:** I did search before asking this question (which looks a bit classic I know), the closest questions I could find were about **window.onload vs <body onload="">**, **other alternatives to window.onload**, etc.

**Edit:** I've created this test case [onload vs window.onload](http://jsperf.com/onload-window-onload), which proves how faster is onload. I would really go for this kind of micro optimisations because why not? They can be cool sometimes.

Comment: onload and window.onload are synonymous to my knowledge

Comment: "onload ... **faster** than window.onload" - how are you testing this? I struggle to think that you could even measure a performance difference between the two. There is certainly no performance difference that would be a factor in real-world code.

Comment: Well I mean **assigning to onload** is faster, I tried it on jsperf at times on different browsers, the results were not arguable at all. here's a new test case http://jsperf.com/onload-vs-window-onload I know it's still considered as a micro optimisation but it's also something that you can learn once and apply always

Comment: Your new test doesn't appear to test anything (you are simply referencing the property) and naturally both tests return _exactly_ the same result for me (in Chrome 28). However, as you state above, an assignment operation does appear to produce different results and `onload` would appear to be marginally quicker than `window.onload` in this respect. http://jsperf.com/onload-vs-window-onload/2 Although, this is a micro^2 optimisation. :)

Comment: My bad, I posted the wrong link http://jsperf.com/onload-window-onload

Answer (score 3):

Both are the same... When you call onload by itself then javascript assumes that it's a global property which is a property of the window object. So basically if you don't specifically say it's window.onload then the javascript engine will do it for you.

```
if (onload === window.onload) {
   alert("it's the same");  //true
}
```

So as long as you don't care about strict mode you shouldn't have any problem with modern browsers. However it's considered better to use the full window.onload instead of just onload. You're not gaining much by not typing the extra 7 characters.

Comment: Yes, I need an explanation to that "however". And the 7 characters sentence isn't needed, I already said that onload is faster not just shorter. Concerning your answer, please see my first comment under the Kaizo's answer.

Comment: It is considered better practise (to use `window.onload`) because it avoids ambiguity, is easier to read, and thus makes your code more portable and less prone to error. You probably wouldn't hesitate to use `window.top`, but the same principle applies.

Answer (score 1):

All global functions and variables are inside window object. So when you are using `onload` you are using `window.onload`.

When calling something inside a namespace you have a performance cost: it has to get the object window and then the property onload.

When calling a global variable without window you have the risk that it is redefined inside its scope:

```
function () {
  var onLoad = function() {alert("foo")};
  function () {
    onLoad();
  }
}
```

In this example onload alerts "foo";

So you asked `are there any real disadvantages related to using the direct onload assignment`:

The onload may be redefined and the code may not work.

Comment: if(XMLHttpRequest) doesn't work in some old IE browsers while if(window.XMLHttpRequest) does, so taking the general rule is not enough I believe.

Comment: @Kaizo: In the above code, `onLoad` would need to be all lowercase to hide the global `onload` property - assuming that is what you are demonstrating.

Comment: @heytools: What do you mean by "the general rule"? Your example seems to highlight a browser quirk rather than relating to Kaizo's code. What Kaizo's code attempts to show is that `onload` in a local scope does not necessarily refer to the global onload property (ie. `window.onload`) - it is ambiguous. Whereas `window.onload` does. The local `onload` variable _hides_ the global `onload` property in the scope chain.

Comment: @w3d General rule = All global functions and variables are inside window object. I know how to use Chrome and verify that window.onload == onload, but that's not enough to conclude that it's always the case even in the oldest browsers/devices.

Comment: That's the point, it's not always the case. `window.onload` does not necessarily equal `onload` when you are not in the global scope. Just looking at your example again, it's not a browser quirk, you should never use `if (globalVar)` (as in XMLHttpRequest) because when `globalVar` has not been defined this throws an exception, whereas `window.globalVar` simply returns _undefined_.