# Which JavaScript functions are called when page loads?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to find out which JavaScript functions are called when a page is loaded?

One way is to use alert but if a file is too big ( in my case 5000+ lines ), it would be too difficult to use alert.

**I want to find out is there anything in FireBug or Developer Tools that shows the order in which functions are called**

Thanks

**By the way, thanks to the person who gave negative comment**

Comment: window.onload() function will be called first

Comment: I assume he is asking about what functions are being called from his custom JavaScript file during page load.

Comment: It isn't possible to get a nice list of functions. You can step through your code using a debugger/break point to see where your code goes. But this will not help with events being fired on page load.

Comment: you must have to understand the code. it will save time and frustration

Comment: @PushkerYadav Sometimes knowing codes didn't help , Bugs and issues comes , and it doesn't means good codes dosen't need debgging

Comment: Actually, I know the onload & $(function(){, console.log  stuff. I just wanted to know is there anything in Developer Tools or FireBug which displays the order, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The Simple Solutions(tedious for you if you have 5000+ line codes) To Your Queries is
Debbuging

There are many way you can debug Your Javascript code

A)The Chrome DevTools include a number of useful tools to help make debugging JavaScript less painful.|
The Sources panel lets you debug your JavaScript code. It provides a graphical interface to the V8 debugger. Follow the steps below to explore the Sources panel:

Open a site on chrome
Open the DevTools window.
If it is not already selected, select Sources.

B)You can use FireBug Chrome tool But i Beleive Chroe Debugger is handy
but Choose Opera For Optimum result

path
Internet Explorer 8 (Developer Tools - F12). Anything else is second rate in Internet Explorer land
Firefox and Firebug. Hit F12 to display.

Safari (Show Menu Bar, Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop menu bar)

Google Chrome JavaScript Console (F12 or (Ctrl + Shift + J)). 
Mostly the same browser as Safari, but Safari is better IMHO.
Opera (Tools -> Advanced -> Developer Tools)

Answer (score 0):

use window.onload is perfect to your request

```
window.onload = function(){

        alert("the page is loaded!!!");

    };
```

it was tested [onload=function vs window.onload=function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473675/onload-function-vs-window-onload-function)

```
window.onload // works in all tested browsers
onload // works in all tested browsers, faster than window.onload
```

so it can't fail... use it, for me is the best way

**<kbd>[Live CODE](http://cssdeck.com/labs/galxzuue)</kbd>**

Comment: I saw few browsers ignoring window.onload, but executing <body onload='func()'>.

Comment: here is the explain you are saying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473675/onload-function-vs-window-onload-function